# Using ThreadPoolExecutor and AsyncTask

Tags: java, android

When using ThreadPoolExecutor can I use AsyncTask as the Runnable in my queue?  Or does this defeat the purpose?

```
//A holder for various tasks
private final LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>(5);

//Thread Pool Executor
private final ThreadPoolExecutor tpe = new ThreadPoolExecutor(3, 3, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An AsyncTask is not a Runnable so you can't really use that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice approach if you need to manage your own task in a more custom way. Use queues and executors, the pass runnables or callables to them.
http://ugiagonzalez.com/2012/07/02/theres-life-after-asynctasks-in-android/