# Can we create two ThreadPoolExecutor running on android?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

AsyncTask is managing a thread pool with 5 core thread. Once we start to use AsyncTask, it will start to set up this thread pool on android phone.

The reason I don't want to AsyncTask is because I am going to create a service, and start threads from service, which means there is not much UI updates from task.
However, asynctask has to been created and execute on UI thread.

So I am going to create another different thread pool which will be used to manage this kind of threads. What I am worrying about is that if I create another thread pool with 5 core threads, would that be too much threads(10 core threads) running on the android? will that slow it down and cause bad performance?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As Alex said ,You will need to use method `executeOnExecutor()` to start it with your own executor.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#executeOnExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20Params...%29

There seems to be number of gotchas, so read carefully the entire page for `AsyncTask`.

So yes, you can create your own `ThreadPoolExecutor` and use it with `AsyncTask`.

And also check this,

[Using ThreadPoolExecutor and AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2251806/using-threadpoolexecutor-and-asynctask)

Comment: No matter AsyncTask using executeOnExecutor() or execute(), both of them will have to be running on UI thread.If I want to run this task from background thread, how would you achieve that? Thanks.